# iterating panel control

Tags: c#, iteration, panel

I tried to find the answer by googling but no luck.
I designed form with panel containing textboxes so I can iterate through its controls
and save every textbox in an array (so I can iterate the array when I want to), 
the thing is I couldn't find which property the panel knows how to arrange the order to iterate the controls inside it, which is the first, second,etc..
I thought maybe it's by tag, but when I changed them to my likings it didn't change anything. 
so I wonder - how can you tell the panel iteration to go through the controls as you prefer? 
which property do you need change?

```
private void CreateTxtArr()
{
     txts = new TextBox[8];
     for (int i = 0; i < pnlTxt.Controls.Count; i++)
        txts[i] = (TextBox)pnlTxt.Controls[i];
}
```

Comment: Cab you please elaborate on what you are trying to do? My understanding is that you are trying to get these textboxes in a specific order. Right?

Comment: yes , i did solve it by changing it in the designer but i felt very like it is a good way to waste time.

Comment: this what i try to do generally: i have datagrid and i'm "binding" it to textboxes so i'd like the textboxes to be at same order at it is on the dg.. when i used this algorithm the order was messed up and i have no idea which inner variable is the one that is being used when you iterate the panel(like the code above).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**is**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator to check if `the child control` of panel `is` `TextBox`

```
private void CreateTxtArr()
{
     txts = new TextBox[8];
     for (int i = 0; i < pnlTxt.Controls.Count; i++)
         if( pnlTxt.Controls[i] is TextBox)
               txts[i] = (TextBox)pnlTxt.Controls[i];
}
```

Comment: You can also cast with <as> keyword

Comment: Yes that could be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .Net 3.5 or higher, you can do it pretty easly with Linq:

```
private void CreateTxtArray()
{
    // txts is an Array of TextBox
    var txts = (from Control ctrl in pnlTxt.Controls
                where ctrl is TextBox
                select ctrl as TextBox).ToArray();
}
```

Is a simpler way to iterate, in all cases

**EDIT**: this is an old answer I had forgotten about, below there is an even simpler way to do that

```
private void CreateTxtArray()
{
    // txts is an Array of TextBox
    var txts = pnlTxt.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
}
```